# Is it valid to incorporate the values I resampled from my binary dataset into a regression analysis?

Tags: r, regression, probability, binomial-distribution, resampling

I have binary [dataset](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AuvDWe9kv3Dqj8IqMhAbfZD8t0aLKA?e=6hqbiL) consisting of 15 zeros and 40 ones. To address potential bias in my data, I have calculated the probability of success from each cell by fitting a glm with binomial family as follows:

```
# Fit a generalized linear model (GLM) with binomial family
model <- glm(predation ~ treatment, data = data, family = binomial())

# Extract the fitted probabilities of success
fitted_probs <- predict(model, type = "response")
```

Then, I generated a new random data sample based on these probabilities and extracted the modified variable:

```
modified_variable <- rbinom(length(fitted_probs), 1, fitted_probs)
```

My question is: Does it make sense to use this new resampled data in regression or chi-square tests?

Any references or resources related to this topic would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just run the regression on your original data?

Comment: No, nothing in particular, though I was afraid of having complete separation. However, I noticed that the resampled data were even more biased than the original one.

Comment: What do you mean by "biased"? Note that this is a technical term in statistics with a specific meaning related to expected value.

Comment: Apologies for the newbness. By biased I was referring to the lots of 1s compared to the few 0s.

Comment: Is treatment a binary predictor?

Comment: Treatment consists of multiple categories, three to be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have independent, binary responses ("predation") and a single predictor variable ("treatment"), your initial code looks correct. Resampling can't help with complete separation.

Comment: May I ask under what circumstances it is advisable to resample data? Additionally, is it possible to utilize the probabilities of success themselves in modeling approaches? I would greatly appreciate any references or resources related to this topic.

Comment: 1. Resampling is typically used when bootstrapped standard errors (SEs) are sought, e.g., when estimated asymptotic SEs provide a poor approximation to the true SDs of the estimators.
2. You don't know the true probabilities of success, so you can't use them. Even if you did, they wouldn't help you here. If you have independent, binary responses, each with a probability of success that depends only on treatment, then the binomial GLM is, by definition, the true model. You don't need to consider other approaches.

Comment: The same would apply even if I have other grouping factors, say, exposing the treatments to different categorical conditions, or if I have a continuous predictor instead of a binary one?

Comment: Besides that, does the resampling I performed in the code above increase the chances of type I or type II errors?

Comment: Yes, my comments apply regardless of the nature of your predictors.

Comment: I'm not sure about Type I and II error probabilities. But, in general, for large samples, likelihood-based inferential procedures (like your original analysis) are the most powerful. You don't gain anything by resampling. Even if you have a relatively small sample in your context, the likelihood ratio test of the effect of treatment should perform well (i.e., be approximately valid and relatively powerful).